# Need a VBA code to select sheets matching names in list then save to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little tricky VBA I'm trying to create. What I currently have is two other macros which search two sheets for vendor names and creates new sheets with their specific information. This leaves me with approx 40 sheets, now what I'm trying to do is write a macro that will search for the vendor name in the sheet title and save all the sheets associated with that vendor to a new workbook (if a file exists update the current sheets in that workbook). I will have a list of vendors in one sheet that I would like to use as the search criteria. Here is an example of the first macro I run

```
Sub ERP_POS()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim bAF As Boolean

    Set ws1 = Sheets("ERP_POS")
    Set rng = Range("Database") bAF = ws1.AutoFilterMode


   'extract a list of Sales Reps With ws1
     .Columns("P:P").Copy _
       Destination:=.Range("X1")
     .Columns("X:X").AdvancedFilter _
       Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
       CopyToRange:=.Range("Y1"), Unique:=True
     r = .Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
     .Columns("X:X").ClearContents

     'set up Criteria Area
     .Range("X1").Value = .Range("P1").Value

     For Each c In .Range("Y2:Y" & r)

       'add the rep name to the criteria area
       .Range("X2").Value = _
             "=""="" & " & Chr(34) & c.Value & Chr(34)

       'add new sheet (if required)
       'and run advanced filter
       If WksExists("ERP_POS" & " " & c.Value) Then
         Sheets("ERP_POS" & " " & c.Value).Cells.Clear
         rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
          CriteriaRange:=.Range("X1:X2"), _
           CopyToRange:=Sheets("ERP_POS" & " " & c.Value).Range("A1"), _
            Unique:=False
       Else
         Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
         wsNew.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
         wsNew.Name = "ERP_POS" & " " & c.Value
         rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
             CriteriaRange:=.Range("X1:X2"), _
             CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), _
             Unique:=False
       End If
     Next

     .Select
     .Columns("Y:X").EntireColumn.Delete

     If bAF = True Then
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter
     End If

    End With
End Sub
Function WksExists(wksName As String) As Boolean
     On Error Resume Next
     WksExists = CBool(Len(Worksheets(wksName).Name) > 0) 
End Function
```

And here is where I have gotten using that and recoring my own macro but haven't figured out how to create the array function with variables derived from the search, or to get the search to work at creating the c.value.

```
Sub Test1234() ' ' Test1234 Macro ' Dim ws As Worksheet Dim ws2 As
    Worksheet ws = Worksheet.Name

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         If ws.Name Like "*CompanyA*" Then
             Set ws2 = Worksheet.Name
             Sheets(ws2).Select
             Sheets(ws2).Copy
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Lovley.xlsx", _
         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        End If
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1 'Ensure to have this command at the top of the module

Sub Lst_Vendors_Wbk_Set()
Const kPath As String = "D:\StackOverFlow\Answers\" 'Change as required
Dim rTrg As Range, rCll As Range, sVendor As String
    'Assuming list of vendors is located at Wsh [Vendors] Column [A] - change as required
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendors")
        Rem Set Target Range
        Set rTrg = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        Rem Work List of Vendors
        For Each rCll In rTrg.Cells
            sVendor = rCll.Value2
            If Not sVendor = Empty Then
                If Not (Wsh_Find_And_Copy_To_New_Wbk(sVendor, kPath)) Then
                    MsgBox "No sheet found for vendor: [" & sVendor & "]"

    End If: End If: Next: End With
End Sub


Function Wsh_Find_And_Copy_To_New_Wbk(sKey As String, sPathFilename As String) As Boolean
Dim Wsh As Worksheet, aWsh() As String
    Rem Validate Key
    If sKey = Empty Then GoTo ExitTkn

    Rem Get Worksheet Array To Be Copied Into A New Wbk
    If IsEmpty(aWsh) Then Stop
    For Each Wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Wsh.Name Like "*" & sKey & "*" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ReDim Preserve aWsh(1 + UBound(aWsh))
            If err.Number <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve aWsh(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            aWsh(UBound(aWsh)) = Wsh.Name
    End If: Next

    Rem Copy Worksheet Array Into A New Wbk
    On Error GoTo ExitTkn
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(aWsh).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPathFilename & sKey, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Rem Set Results
    Wsh_Find_And_Copy_To_New_Wbk = True

ExitTkn:
End Function
```

Suggest to visit the following pages:

[Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html), [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx), [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)
[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [Workbook Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835568.aspx)
[Worksheet Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Comment: seems to throw an error code 9 on `ThisWorkbook.sheets(aWsh).Copy`, Also where sKey is I need that to be a variable from another sheet and that variable will be used as the file name.  The sheet containing the variable list is, "Disti_List".

Comment: @B_ROB Sorry forget to include the `Option Base 1` have edited the post please try now...

Comment: **`Error 13 - Type mismatch`** - It means no `Sheet` was found with a similar name, so check what you are feeding `sKey` with most probably you made a typing error.

Comment: looked to be a bug saved it, closed excel reopen and it worked.  The part I'm working on now is the c.value from the previous process.  Need to have the c.value from sheet "Disti_list" feed into sKey, this is what I was trying `Dim sKey As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim Wsh As Worksheet, aWsh() As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Range
sKey = c.Value 'Change as required
Set rng = Range("Disti_list")
 r = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In .Range("H2:H" & r)`

Comment: @B_ROB See revised answer added the procedure to search the list and changed the procedure to create the workbooks to a function. Change path, worksheet name and column as required.

Comment: thanks that works... still a few little bugs if it stops and you have books open it seems to error out when running it again and then your stuck with 20 open windows; also I would have liked to preserve the Pivot sheets in the destination workbooks but this is a huge leap from where I was manually creating sheets and workbooks.  Thank you so much